# inserting JSON decoded values into table

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my code of json decode and insert into the table after decoding. I am not getting how to insert implode values into table and nested json values .

```
include 'config.php'; /* datdabase connection*/
    class User {
public function update()
{
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('data.txt');
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$name=array();
    foreach($data as $item)
    {
$name[]=$item['v'];

        }
$val=implode(',',$name);
        echo"$val";
        $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO incident_main(inc_patientName,inc_patientAge,inc_patientGender,inc_patientMobile,inc_patientAddress,inc_patientWard,inc_type)  VALUES('..........') )");
        if(!$sql)
        {
            echo "Failed to insert the data into table";

    }
}}

$obj=new User(); 
$obj->update()
```

This is my data.txt file. Here "n" is name of table  column and "v" is value which is to be inserted.

```
{
    "user_id": "user123",
    "time_stamp": "epoch",
    "lat": 52.25,
    "lon": 85.45,
    "mainreport":    [{
         "n": "date_of_diagnosis",
         "v": "epoch"
        },
        {
         "n": "name",
         "v": "abc"
        },
        {
         "n": "age",
         "v": 20
        },
        {
         "n": "gender",
         "v": "male"
        },
        {
         "n": "address",
         "v": "some address"
        },
        {
         "n": "location_gis_Stamp",
         "v": "word-1"
        },
        {
         "n": "mobile_number",
         "v": "some number"
        },
        {
         "n": "type_of_application",
         "v": "other",
         "nested": [{
             "n": "other",
             "v": "reason"
         }]}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following errors in your query

1. Proper space between table name and fields `incident_main(inc_patientName,inc_patientAge,........`
2. You used an extra `)` near values in your query. `inc_treatment,inc_untraced)  VALUES('..........') )"`
3. Enclose the database value with 'value', it will be fine if you have only integer value so you don't need to add `''`.

Try like this:

```
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $name[]=$item['v'];

    // Check and get Nested Values
    if( isset($item['nested']) && is_array($item['nested']) ) {
        foreach($item['nested'] as $val) {
            $name[] = $val['v'];
        }
    }

}


$val=implode("','",$name);
// epoch', 'abc', '20', 'male', 'some address', 'word-1', 'some number', 'other', 'reason
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO incident_main (inc_patientName,inc_patientAge,inc_patientGender,inc_patientMobile,inc_patientAddress,inc_patientWard,inc_type,inc_diagnosis,inc_recurrence,inc_hospitalized,inc_treatment,inc_untraced) 
        VALUES('".$val."') ");
```

Please use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: nested  json is  not imploded .

Comment: nested is working properly thanks,but i have one more problem i edited my data.txt file can u plz have a look on that.

Comment: You should come with your actual code instead of changing the question time to time. Use `$data['mainreport']` in your foreach loop

Comment: Thanks its working, the problem is i am not being able to add multiple rows present in data.txt file. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Values should be in quotation mark. Please try this;

```
$val='"' . implode('","',$name) . '"';
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO incident_main(inc_patientName,inc_patientAge,inc_patientGender,inc_patientMobile,inc_patientAddress,inc_patientWard,inc_type,inc_diagnosis,inc_recurrence,inc_hospitalized,inc_treatment,inc_untraced)  VALUES($val);");
```

Additionaly, mysql_ functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5. Use PDO or mysqli instead of the mysql_ functions.

http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

To use the values you can replace it like this in your sql:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO incident(inc_patientName,inc_patientAge,inc_patientGender,inc_patientMobile,inc_patientAddress,inc_patientWard,inc_type,inc_diagnosis,inc_recurrence,inc_hospitalized,inc_treatment,inc_untraced)". " VALUES( '".$val."')";
```

The code above will give the following result:

> INSERT INTO
>   incident(inc_patientName,inc_patientAge,inc_patientGender,inc_patientMobile,inc_patientAddress,inc_patientWard,inc_type,inc_diagnosis,inc_recurrence,inc_hospitalized,inc_treatment,inc_untraced) VALUES( 'epoch','abc','20','male','some address','word-1','some
>   number','other')

> However, in your code you imploded the values with "," ,but in sql
>   string values are encoded with double quotes ""

To solve this issues replace your code as follows:

```
$val=implode("','",$name);
```